# Select rows with the same attribute1 and different attribute2

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table

```
+----+------+---------+
| ID | CODE | COUNTRY |
+----+------+---------+
|  1 |   05 | France  |
|  2 |   05 | France  |
|  3 |   06 | Germany |
|  4 |   07 | France  |
|  5 |   07 | Italy   |
+----+------+---------+
```

and I need to select rows with the same code but different country.
So the result should be:

```
+------+---------+
| CODE | COUNTRY |
+------+---------+
|   07 | France  |
|   07 | Italy   |
+------+---------+
```

I tried

```
SELECT t1.code AS code, t1.country AS country
FROM countries AS t1, countries AS t2
WHERE t1.code = t2.code
AND t1.country <> t2.country;
```

and it works for the table in the example above.
But if the table looks like this:

```
+----+------+---------+
| ID | CODE | COUNTRY |
+----+------+---------+
|  1 |   05 | France  |
|  2 |   05 | France  |
|  3 |   06 | Germany |
|  4 |   07 | France  |
|  5 |   07 | Italy   |
|  6 |   07 | Italy   |
+----+------+---------+
```

the result is:

```
+------+---------+
| CODE | COUNTRY |
+------+---------+
|   07 | Italy   |
|   07 | Italy   |
|   07 | France  |
|   07 | France  |
+------+---------+
```

but should be the same as above.

(I work with MS Access, so the query should work on Access)

Comment: Consider `SELECT DISTINCT`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `distinct`

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.code AS code, t1.country AS country
FROM countries AS t1, countries AS t2
WHERE t1.code = t2.code
AND t1.country <> t2.country;
```

Comment: I do sometimes wonder if I'm reading the same question as other people. How does this "select rows with the same code but different country"?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever The key here is OP query already works `and it works for the table in the example above` so only need distinct to remove the duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MIN` and `MAX` to spot Codes where the Country is different, then use that to select all rows:

```
SELECT * FROM countries WHERE Code IN (
  SELECT Code
  FROM countries
  GROUP BY Code
  HAVING MIN(Country) < MAX(Country)
)
```

Comment: The result is 3 records: France, Italy, Italy.